# mongo query join- get total records as key from another collection

Tags: mongodb, join, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections:

**quiz_customer_record** collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6ec91cbf74d27430b9c24f"),
    "quiz_id" : "5f3a33185a1cd35632b8c98c",
    "user_id" : "5efae8bed5c5f06f30a057ff",
    "name" : "ABC",
    "qualification" : "ttt",
    "time_required" : "0:13 Mins",
    "questions_attempted" : 2,
    "total_quiz_questions" : 2,
    "attempt_date" : "2020-09-26T04:52:48.169Z"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6eca82bf74d27430b9c252"),
    "quiz_id" : "5f3a33185a1cd35632b8c98c",
    "user_id" : "5f6ec9ba3b502398598a5ade",
    "name" : "Test",
    "qualification" : "BSC",
    "time_required" : "0:6 Mins",
    "questions_attempted" : 2,
    "total_quiz_questions" : 2,
    "attempt_date" : "2020-09-26T04:58:46.060Z"
}
```

**dummy** collection

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6ec906bf74d27430b9c24d"),
    "user_id" : "5efae8bed5c5f06f30a057ff",
    "question_id" : "5f6ec888bf74d27430b9c248",
    "quiz_id" : "5f3a33185a1cd35632b8c98c",
    "selected_answer" : [ 
        "rgdfgdfg"
    ],
    "attempt_date" : "2020-09-26T04:52:25.977Z",
    "correct_answer" : [ 
        "rgdfgdfg"
    ],
    "result" : true
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6eca82bf74d27430b9c250"),
    "user_id" : "5f6ec9ba3b502398598a5ade",
    "question_id" : "5f6ec888bf74d27430b9c248",
    "quiz_id" : "5f3a33185a1cd35632b8c98c",
    "selected_answer" : [ 
        "rgdfgdfg"
    ],
    "attempt_date" : "2020-09-26T04:58:46.060Z",
    "correct_answer" : [ 
        "rgdfgdfg"
    ],
    "result" : true
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6eca82bf74d27430b9c251"),
    "user_id" : "5f6ec9ba3b502398598a5ade",
    "question_id" : "5f6ec8b4bf74d27430b9c24b",
    "quiz_id" : "5f3a33185a1cd35632b8c98c",
    "selected_answer" : [ 
        "sdfsdf"
    ],
    "attempt_date" : "2020-09-26T04:58:46.060Z",
    "correct_answer" : [ 
        "sdfsdf"
    ],
    "result" : true
}
```

From the 2nd(dummy collection i want the total records per user)

I am using this query in which i need modifications:

```
 db.quiz_customer_record.aggregate([{ $match: { quiz_id:"5f3a33185a1cd35632b8c98c"}},
    {
        $sort: { attempt_date: -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$user_id",
            result1: { $first: "$attempt_date" },
            quiz_id: { $first: "$quiz_id" },
             o_id: { $first: "$_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: "$o_id",
            user_id: "$_id",
            result1: 1
        }
    }
])
```

this will give the result as:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "attempt_date" : "2020-09-26T04:52:48.169Z",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6ec91cbf74d27430b9c24f"),
    "user_id" : "5efae8bed5c5f06f30a057ff"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "attempt_date" : "2020-09-26T04:58:46.060Z",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6eca82bf74d27430b9c252"),
    "user_id" : "5f6ec9ba3b502398598a5ade"
}
```

Expected Result: (as per `user_id` I need the count of records from dummy collection where `quiz_id` and `attempt_date`(result1 from above query) matches)

```
/* 1 */
{
    "attempt_date" : "2020-09-26T04:52:48.169Z",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6ec91cbf74d27430b9c24f"),
    "user_id" : "5efae8bed5c5f06f30a057ff",
    "total_dummy_rec":0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "attempt_date" : "2020-09-26T04:58:46.060Z",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6eca82bf74d27430b9c252"),
    "user_id" : "5f6ec9ba3b502398598a5ade",
    "total_dummy_rec":2
}
```

where `total_dummy_rec` is the count of total record per user in "dummy" collection.

I am confused on how to approach so i can achieve this result. Help me find a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 2 stages after your pipeline stages,

- `$lookup` to join `dummy` collection, where pass required field in let and in pipeline match condition
- moved `$project` at last and count total document in dummy using `$size`

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "dummy",
      let: {
        quiz_id: "$quiz_id",
        user_id: "$_id",
        attempt_date: "$attempt_date"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$$quiz_id", "$quiz_id"] },
                { $eq: ["$$user_id", "$user_id"] },
                { $eq: ["$$attempt_date", "$attempt_date"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "dummy"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$o_id",
      user_id: "$_id",
      result1: 1,
      total_dummy_rec: {
        $size: "$dummy"
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2KVwiTX08Mr)

Comment: thankyou for quick reply, I executed your solution it needs some changes, In lookup it should also match the quiz id, when i am running this query it is taking the total of "dummy" collection where only userid matches, it should also match quiz_id and attempt_date.

Comment: There is still a problem with the match though, please check this link https://mongoplayground.net/p/hYzUd80Jx04  @turivishal

Comment: when i work this query in my other server where there are many records 1000 approx, it is showing timeout issue and taking much time. Any thoughts?

Comment: add index on condition fields and then try (quiz_id, attempt_date, user_id), read about [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/ )

Comment: actually i am new to this concept, should i create indexes for these 3 fields of first table (quiz_id, attempt_date, user_id) ?? @turivishal

Comment: Yes but you need to learn first index features and use of index, i can't explain here, you need to learn your self from provided link, yes you can create index for that fields.